# Matplotlib visual studio metadata-generation-failed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an issue with downloading matplotlib in visual studio code.

my error at it's basic is

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

but at its length its

```
PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install keyboard
Collecting keyboard
  Using cached keyboard-0.13.5-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Installing collected packages: keyboard
stuff_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' comman
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install keyboard
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\mar.formosaurquhart\st\stuff_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install keyboard
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages (0.13.5)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (7.3 MB)
Collecting pyparsing<3.1,>=2.3.1
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.4-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (46 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz (13.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\MAR~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvqswun5n'
         cwd: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8
    Complete output (12 lines):
    + meson setup C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8 C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8\.mesonpy-a1ohuof6\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8\.mesonpy-a1ohuof6\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
    The Meson build system
    Version: 1.2.0
    Source dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8
    Build dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8\.mesonpy-a1ohuof6\build
    Build type: native build
    Project name: contourpy
    Project version: 1.1.0

    ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

    A full log can be found at C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\contourpy_28e9270cf2c44db18fd40b81f5ad96e8\.mesonpy-a1ohuof6\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/3b/632c003e1dfbc82d32c0466762f2d2cf139d26032626dc65944e38d0e5b9/contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz#sha256=e53046c3863828d21d531cc3b53786e6580eb1ba02477e8681009b6aa0870b21 (from https://pypi.org/simple/contourpy/) (requires-python:>=3.8). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\MAR~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvqswun5n' Check the logs for full command output.    
  Using cached contourpy-1.0.7-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (143 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-10.0.0.tar.gz (50.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting numpy>=1.20
  Using cached numpy-1.25.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (12.7 MB)
Collecting importlib-resources>=3.2.0
  Using cached importlib_resources-6.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0
  Using cached fonttools-4.42.0-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting zipp>=3.1.0
  Using cached zipp-3.16.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\Scripts\python.exe' 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\MAR~1.FOR\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkuj2uvqm'
       cwd: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\pillow_03aac6e8a715462084a8b0e0bbd28b6f
  Complete output (198 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-cpython-39
  creating build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BdfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BlpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BmpImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ContainerIO.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\CurImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\DdsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\EpsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ExifTags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\features.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FitsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FliImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FpxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\FtexImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GbrImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GdImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GifImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpGradientFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GimpPaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IcoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Image.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageChops.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageCms.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageColor.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageDraw2.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageEnhance.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFilter.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageFont.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageGrab.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMath.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMode.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageMorph.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageOps.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePalette.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImagePath.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageQt.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageSequence.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageShow.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageStat.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTk.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageTransform.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImageWin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\ImtImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\IptcImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\JpegPresets.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MicImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpegImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MpoImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\MspImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PaletteFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PalmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcfFontFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PcxImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PdfParser.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PixarImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PsdImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PSDraw.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\PyAccess.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\QoiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SgiImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\SunImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TarIO.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TgaImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\TiffTags.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WalImageFile.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WebPImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\WmfImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XbmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XpmImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_binary.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_deprecate.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_tkinter_finder.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_util.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  copying src\PIL\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-39\PIL
  running egg_info
  writing src\Pillow.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src\Pillow.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src\Pillow.egg-info\requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src\Pillow.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching '*.c'
  warning: no files found matching '*.h'
  warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
  warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'renovate.json'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution    
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution     
  no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'src\Pillow.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext


  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 988, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 346, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 84, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 345, in run
      self.build_extensions()
    File "<string>", line 811, in build_extensions
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 349, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 331, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 248, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\pillow_03aac6e8a715462084a8b0e0bbd28b6f\_custom_build\backend.py", line 53, in build_wheel
      return super().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings, metadata_directory)     
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h11n5ap7\pillow_03aac6e8a715462084a8b0e0bbd28b6f\_custom_build\backend.py", line 47, in run_setup
      return super().run_setup(setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-vo61pk65\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 1005, in <module>
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html


  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
Failed to build pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directlyWARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\Scrip(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> python -mpip install -U pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python\venv\lib\site-packages (21.2.4)
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 21.2.4
    Uninstalling pip-21.2.4:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-21.2.4
Successfully installed pip-23.2.1
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> python -mpip install -U matplotlib    
Collecting matplotlib
  Obtaining dependency information for matplotlib from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/99/6cb77705e4801b4483410b9b917790fdc2da311ec8dd1ed8c9e90320c0e1/matplotlib-3.7.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl.metadata
  Downloading matplotlib-3.7.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz (13.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sn56rrg9\contourpy_7b98591287aa4465b49d10646634c0ad C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sn56rrg9\contourpy_7b98591287aa4465b49d10646634c0ad\.mesonpy-9sxu8bop\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sn56rrg9\contourpy_7b98591287aa4465b49d10646634c0ad\.mesonpy-9sxu8bop\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sn56rrg9\contourpy_7b98591287aa4465b49d10646634c0ad
      Build dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sn56rrg9\contourpy_7b98591287aa4465b49d10646634c0ad\.mesonpy-9sxu8bop\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.1.0
     
      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-sn56rrg9\contourpy_7b98591287aa4465b49d10646634c0ad\.mesonpy-9sxu8bop\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> python -mpip install -U matplotlib  
Collecting matplotlib
  Obtaining dependency information for matplotlib from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/99/6cb77705e4801b4483410b9b917790fdc2da311ec8dd1ed8c9e90320c0e1/matplotlib-3.7.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl.metadata       
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz (13.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
d18e4fc6ba7e0323b9558c36 C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x9h8yges\contourpy_092b96e5d18e4fc6ba7e0323b9558c36\.mesonpy-p0gvd7il\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x9h8yges\contourpy_092b96e5d18e4fc6ba7e0323b9558c36\.mesonpy-p0gvd7il\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x9h8yges\contourpy_092b96e5d18e4fc6ba7e0323b9558c36
      Build dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x9h8yges\contourpy_092b96e5d18e4fc6ba7e0323b9558c36\.mesonpy-p0gvd7il\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.1.0
     
      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x9h8yges\contourpy_092b96e5d18e4fc6ba7e0323b9558c36\.mesonpy-p0gvd7il\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install python-matplotlib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-matplotlib (from versions: none)     
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-matplotlib
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install matplotlib --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.7.2-cp39-cp39-win32.whl (7.3 MB)
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib)
  Using cached contourpy-1.1.0.tar.gz (13.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79rkcmx5\contourpy C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79rkcmx5\contourpy\.mesonpy-kkm20kji\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79rkcmx5\contourpy\.mesonpy-kkm20kji\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.0
      Source dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79rkcmx5\contourpy
      Build dir: C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79rkcmx5\contourpy\.mesonpy-kkm20kji\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: contourpy
      Project version: 1.1.0
     
      ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe
     
      A full log can be found at C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79rkcmx5\contourpy\.mesonpy-kkm20kji\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> contourpy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> pip install matplotlib --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures

Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

option --use-deprecated: invalid choice: 'backtrack-on-build-failures' (choose from 'legacy-resolver')     
(venv) PS C:\Users\mar.formosaurquhart\stuff_python> --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
At line:1 char:3
+ --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
+   ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:1 char:3
+ --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

I have tried `pip install keyboard` I have also tried `pip install matplotlib` but a similar error occured I have tried using I have also tried `pip install --pre matplotlib`  and my pip and other stuff are up to date so that shouldn't be the issue. my code had no other errors and can run on my other python program.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the command below to install your module, in some cases it can helps:

```
pip install keyboard --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Comment: it worked for keyboard module. Do you know how to do matplotlib by any chance?

Comment: I thought the same command would work for it, too. Please run the command for installing matplotlib and send the error log here.